# How repatch signed applet and re-sign it with my own certificate?

Tags: java, applet, certificate, digital-signature

I have 4 signed jars (one of them contains applet class) and want to add some functions to applet. I have their sources. Applet jar depends on other 3 non applet jars, let's call them as helper jars. I see 3 approaches:

1. Create new project, add 3 helper jars as project libraries, copy whole sources of applet jar to new project, add needed functions to applet class. Rebuild project as a jar, sign it with certificate given to me by our national certificate authority.
2. Create new project, add all 4 jars as libraries, create only one class which extends existing applet, build it as jar, sign it with certificate given to me by our national certificate authority. Now my applet codebase contains 5 jars.
3. Create new project, copy all sources of all applets, remove sign by removing .RSA files and manifest file inside jar. Add new functions to applet. Rebuild project as single jar, sign it with certificate given to me by our national certificate authority.

Questions:

1. First and second options may lead to situation, that some jars will be signed with one key (used *as is*), others will be signed with my key. Is it OK?
2. In all 3 choices I have to sign at least one jar with my key. I know, that java 7u51 and higher doesn't allow self-signed jars, but I have certificate given to me by our national certificate authority. Is it OK to use such certificate, will it still be blocked?

I installed root certificates from trusted site, but not fully understand is it necessary or not. AFAIK, my certificate contains url, where certificate can be verified and installations of root certificates forces my JVM  to trust to this URL. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to [sign](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step4.html) all your jars with the **same** certificate
- Yes, an official certificate will suffice

For redistribution you have two possibilities:

1. Make one fat jar and sign it (3rd party libs are "unpacked" and inside)
2. Create an applet.jar out of your sourcecode, and sign it including all your 3rd party libs

Please note that you also need to set the permissions Manifest attributes ([1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step4.html),[2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/secman.html))